# Angular ng-repeat for comma separated strings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a question in angularjs.

In my controller, I've a comma separated string, and I will show it in my index.html(with ng-repeat)

Here is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('TabsDemoCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/performbatch').success(function(data) {
        $scope.string = 'Gzrgh,1,2,1,4,1,1,1,20150304,20180304';
        $scope.arrString = new Array();
        $scope.arrString = $scope.string.split(',');
    });
```

Here is my html :

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
    <td ng-repeat="icerik in arrString">
       {{icerik}}
    </td>
</div>
```

But I couldn't achieve that. Can you help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i've edit it again, it doesn't work still

Comment: You can't have td outside of table. You can use some other html tag elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XOxJtYEBhwFlJn2x4sbv?p=preview) for you

You need to use track by $index because it is having duplicate value in array.

```
ng-repeat="icerik in arrString track by $index"
```

Comment: kudos track by is one thing, also the OP has used `td` which was not displaying. Even in your example, you've replaced it with `p` tag :)

Comment: @mohamedrias i used <p> in my example of plunker .I know it must be the small demo he is trying to show that's why i didn't considered that. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't have `td` outside `table`.

It must be like

```
<div ng-repeat="icerik in arrString track by $index">
       {{icerik}}
</div>
```

Also since some are duplicates items, you must add `track by $index` as well

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/simoworuku/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Answer (score 1):

if you want to repeat s tring saperated with `,`, you shall split the string to an array and the repeat

try this:

```
  $scope.string = $scope.string.split(",");
```

this creates an array from string that is split from `,`.

so your code becomes:

```
myApp.controller('TabsDemoCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/performbatch').success(function(data) {
        $scope.string = 'Gzrgh,1,2,1,4,1,1,1,20150304,20180304';
  $scope.str= str.split(",");
        $scope.arrString = new Array();
        $scope.arrString = $scope.string.split(',');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td ng-repeat="L in Labour.CWCT_Description.split(',') track by $index" >
                                        {{L}}
                                    </td>
```